# find a smaller group of friends from the circle?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I am working on the following problem:

> In a room with people, we will define two persons are friends if they
>   are directly or indirectly friends. If A is a friend with B, and B is
>   a friend with C, then A is a friend of C too. A group of friends is a
>   group of persons where any two persons in the group are friends. Given
>   the list of persons that are directly friends, find the smallest group
>   of friends..

Example:
Input:

```
1<->6 
2<->7
3<->8
4<->9
2<->6
3<->5
```

Groups:

```
1-6-2-7
3-8-5
4-9
```

The number of people in the smallest group is 2 i.e. 4-9 so we should return 2.

I came up with the code below but I don't understand how to use this `holder` map now to get the required output. I am kinda confused here. What is the best way to solve this problem?

```
  private static int findGroups(final List<List<Integer>> inputs) {
    if (inputs == null || inputs.isEmpty()) {
      return 0;
    }
    int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> holder = new HashMap<>();
    for (List<Integer> input : inputs) {
      // storing it in bidirectional way in the map
      List<Integer> l =
          holder.containsKey(input.get(0)) ? holder.get(input.get(0)) : new ArrayList<Integer>();
      l.add(input.get(1));
      holder.put(input.get(0), l);

      List<Integer> l1 =
          holder.containsKey(input.get(1)) ? holder.get(input.get(1)) : new ArrayList<Integer>();
      l1.add(input.get(0));
      holder.put(input.get(1), l1);
    }
    System.out.println(holder);

    // use holder map to get the smaller group here?

    return count;
  }
```

Looks like I need to use recursion here to get smaller groups?

Comment: Graph data structure would be better to use in solving this problem

Comment: Is there a limit to indirect friendships? If A <-> B, B <-> C, and C <-> D, are A and D friends or does it stop at A is a friend of C?

Comment: You can create graph structure and search components.

Comment: You are finding so-called "connected components" on a graph. Described for instance here: - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any better way to solve this problem?

A better approach is to use a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure):

- First, compute the "groups of friends" as a disjoint-set data structure:

  - Initialize a disjoint-set data structure where the elements of the sets will be the people in the room.
  - For each person *p* in the room:

    - Call *MakeSet*(*p*) to initialize a "group of friends" containing just that person.
  - For each direct friendship *p*<sub>1</sub>↔*p*<sub>2</sub>:

    - Call *Union*(*p*<sub>1</sub>, *p*<sub>2</sub>) to unify the "group of friends" that contains *p*<sub>1</sub> with the one that contains *p*<sub>2</sub>.
- Next, compute the sizes of the "groups of friends" as a map:

  - Initialize a map where the keys will be some of the people in the room (namely, the representatives of their respective "groups of friends") and the values will be numbers (namely, the sizes of the various "groups of friends").
  - For each person *p*<sub>1</sub> in the room:

    - Call *Find*(*p*<sub>1</sub>) to find the representative *p*<sub>2</sub> of that person's "group of friends".
    - If the map does not already contain a value for the key *p*<sub>2</sub>, insert the value 0 for that key.
    - Increment the value for the key *p*<sub>2</sub>.
- Lastly, compute the result:

  - Initialize a result to a large value, e.g. the number of people in the room.
  - For each value (= size of a "group of friends") in the map:

    - If this value is less than the result, set the result equal to this value.
  - Return the result.

By the way, the technical name for the operation you're performing is *[transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)*: the "are friends" relation is the transitive closure of the "are directly friends" relation. (However, the algorithms described at the Wikipedia article for that are not optimal for your problem, because they don't take advantage of the fact that your relation is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation).)

Comment: can you provide an  example basis on your suggestion? I am not able to understand currently on how to approach this problem?

Comment: @flash: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "an example basis".

Comment: what I am trying to understand is how to use disjoint data structure here for this problem?

Comment: @flash: As the answer says: "Iterate over the list of direct friendships; for each one, unite the two friends' friend-groups."

Comment: @flash, if you are still not satisfied with this updated answer, could you tell why? So we can improve it or produce a better one.

Comment: Yes, you can use the disjoint sets, but if the "list of direct friends" never changes, I think it is easier to do a standard search over a graph (DFS or BFS).

Comment: @Marwin: The DFS and BFS approaches are fine -- and I've upvoted your answer -- but they require transforming the graph representation into one that lets you easily look up the neighbors of a given vertex. I suggested the disjoint-set data structure because it requires only O(|V|) extra space and is likely to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code, I've wrote out of curiousity about your problem. I don't know much about graphs, but it uses recursion, like you requested.

Basically you go through the input and for every person, you create an `ArrayList<Integer>`. In that array are the people who are that person's immediate friends. For instance, for `1: {6}, for 2: {7, 6}, for 3: {8, 5}`. Then, to get *all* friends of person 2, you create a compoud `ArrayList<Integer>` array by getting together arrays for person 7 and 6 (excluding duplicates). So, the recursion could be used in a way that a function `getAllFriends(Integer person)` would have to return the `getAllFriends(Integer person2)` for that person's immediate friends as well.

So, the code could look like something like this:

```
public class Test  {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String input = "1<->6\n" +
            "2<->7\n" +
            "3<->8\n" +
            "4<->9\n" +
            "2<->6\n" +
            "3<->5";

            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> friends = processInput(input);  //getting data from the input string and storing it in a structured way
            System.out.println(getAllFriends(1, friends, new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(1);}}));  //output: [1, 6, 2, 7]. Double brackets create an anonymous inner class, you add to the result the id of a person whose friends you're collecting
            }

        public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> processInput(String input) throws Exception  {
            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();

            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input));
            String line=null;
            while( (line=bufReader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                Integer personLeft =  Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0, line.indexOf("<")));
                Integer personRight =Integer.valueOf(line.substring(line.indexOf(">")+1, line.length()));

                System.out.println(personLeft + ": " + personRight);

                if (!result.containsKey(personLeft))  {
                    result.put(personLeft, new ArrayList<Integer>());
                }

                result.get(personLeft).add(personRight);

                if (!result.containsKey(personRight))  {
                    result.put(personRight, new ArrayList<Integer>());
                }

                result.get(personRight).add(personLeft);
            }


            return result;

        }

        public static ArrayList<Integer>  getAllFriends(Integer person, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> friends, ArrayList<Integer> result)  {
            for (Integer personFriend: friends.get(person))  {
                    if (!result.contains(personFriend))  {
                        result.add(personFriend);  //add a person, if it wasn't added before
                        getAllFriends(personFriend, friends, result);  //check out that person's friends
                    }
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```